# Writing Name Using Bezier Curves In C#

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, bezier

I have to make a program that uses C# Generated Graphics to make a replica of my name that I wrote in cursive. Twist is, I have to use Bezier Curves. I've already called a function to make Bezier Curves using 4 points and a gravity concept. My question to you is, What would be the easiest way to make around 10 curves.

Here is my function for a Bezier Curve.

```
public static void bezierCurve(
     Graphics g, 
     double p1x, double p1y, 
     double p2x, double p2y, 
     double p3x, double p3y, 
     double p4x, double p4y)
{
    double t, r1x, r4x, r1y, r4y;
    float x, y;

    Pen black = new Pen(Color.Black);

    r1x = 3 * (p2x - p1x);
    r4x = 3 * (p4x - p3x);

    r1y = 3 * (p2y - p1y);
    r4y = 3 * (p4y - p3y);

    t = 0;
    while (t <= 1)
    {
        x = (float) ((2 * Math.Pow(t, 3) - 3 * Math.Pow(t, 2) + 1) * p1x
            + (-2 * Math.Pow(t, 3) + 3 * Math.Pow(t, 2)) * p4x
            + (Math.Pow(t, 3) - 2 * Math.Pow(t, 2) + t) * r1x
            + (Math.Pow(t, 3) - Math.Pow(t, 2)) * r4x);
        y = (float) ((2 * Math.Pow(t, 3) - 3 * Math.Pow(t, 2) + 1) * p1y
            + (-2 * Math.Pow(t, 3) + 3 * Math.Pow(t, 2)) * p1y
            + (Math.Pow(t, 3) - 2 * Math.Pow(t, 2) + t) * r1y
            + (Math.Pow(t, 3) - Math.Pow(t, 2)) * r4y);

        g.DrawRectangle(black, x, y, 1, 1);

        t = t + 0.01;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing that for me Drew. It wasn't coding properly for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking some vector editing software, e.g. InkScape or Corel, draw your name with beziers using that software, then save as .SVG. The SVG format is easy to understand, [here is an example of encoding a bezier path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands). Copy the coordinates from the path into your program. Alternatively, use a piece of graph paper to get the coordinates by hand.

C# already has a function for drawing Beziers, see [Graphics.DrawBezier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt9t4wah.aspx), that is going to be much more efficient (and producing better-looking results) than your implementation.